# Java Repaint gridlayout

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to repaint a snake game I am creating on the new game action.It is working but it isn't clearing the old snake body or blocks from the screen.

```
public class View extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -2542001418764869760L;
public static int viewWidth = 20;
public static int viewHeight = 20;
private SidePanel side;

private JMenuBar menuBar;
private JMenuItem newGameButton;
private JMenu menu, mode;
private SnakeController sController;

private GamePanel gamePanel;

/*
 * Initialize the game's panels and add them to the window.
 */
public View() {

    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menu = new JMenu("Menu");
    menuBar.add(menu);

    newGameButton = new JMenuItem("New Game");
    menu.add(newGameButton);
    newGameButton.addActionListener(this);

    mode = new JMenu("Mode");
    menuBar.add(mode);

    this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    this.gamePanel = new GamePanel(this);

    this.side = new SidePanel(this);

    this.add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(side, BorderLayout.EAST);

    Tuple position = new Tuple(10, 10);
    sController = new SnakeController(position, side, gamePanel);
    this.addKeyListener((KeyListener) new Listener());
    // this.requestFocus();

    pack();

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    View window = new View();
    window.setTitle("og-snake");
    window.setSize(700, 400);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == newGameButton) {
        System.out.println("clicked");

        gamePanel.removeAll();
        gamePanel.revalidate();
        gamePanel.repaint();

        Tuple position = new Tuple(10, 10);

        sController = new SnakeController(position, side, gamePanel);
        sController.start();


    }

}
```

This is my main class that basically makes a view adds a side panel and board panel.The action performed is done on the new game action on the game panel.

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

public static ArrayList<ArrayList<ColorCell>> snakeGrid;
public static int viewWidth = 20;
public static int viewHeight = 20;
ArrayList<ColorCell> data; 
SnakeController sc ;
private View game;

public GamePanel(View game) {
    this.game = game;
    this.snakeGrid = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ColorCell>>();
    this.data = new ArrayList<ColorCell>();
    for (int i = 0; i < viewWidth; i++) {
        data = new ArrayList<ColorCell>();
        for (int j = 0; j < viewHeight; j++) {
            ColorCell c = new ColorCell(2);
            data.add(c);
        }
        snakeGrid.add(data);
    }
    setLayout(new GridLayout(viewWidth, viewHeight, 0, 0));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400)); 

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for (int i = 0; i < viewWidth; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < viewHeight; j++) {
            add(snakeGrid.get(i).get(j).viewCell);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    gamePanel.removeAll();
    gamePanel.fillGrid();
    gamePanel.revalidate();
    gamePanel.repaint();
    Tuple position = new Tuple(10, 10);
    this.gamePanel = new GamePanel(this);
    this.add(gamePanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

That code doesn't really do anything. When you add a component to the CENTER of the BorderLayout it does not replace the original component.

The way Swing painting works is that the last component added is painted first. So this means the newly added panel is painted and then the original panel is painted over top of the newly added panel.

So, since you have logic to remove all the components from the original gamePanel, there is no need to create a new gamePanel. Just reset the state of the game panel.

Comment: Okay i see now, but now its just recreating spawning more not removing the old snake. I tried to clear the snakegrid object and refill but when ever i clearedBoard, i would get the first image. I added another image for my update

Comment: An image doesn't help. You wrote your logic. You need to add "reset" logic to your code to clear the board. I can't tell you how to do that because I don't know how your game works.

Comment: Hey I have updated the code with all the logic, as for my issue I think its the way i am initializing and assigning to the snakeGrid Array when i repaint. I tried to clear the entire snakeGrid arraylist but this didnt work either.